# Will these skills in machine learning be relevant in fall 2023?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a masters in civil engineering but would like to work within IT. From my education I have a mathematical and data analysis background. I'm considering taking a course in machine learning to learn the methods/tools currently used in data analysis. I graduated from uni 10yrs ago, so my skills in IT are probably outdated.

The course in machine learning will take 1 year to complete and will cover the following:

- has knowledge of processes and methods that are used to solve data-driven problemsList item
- has knowledge of processes tools that are used for programming with Python
- has knowledge of data collection and preparation that is used for Machine Learning tasks
- has knowledge of tools, development methodologies and processes that are used in Machine Learning applications
- can update his/her knowledge related to data mining, programming and machine learning
- has a knowledge of the IT industry and is familiar with the importance of Machine Learning
- understands the importance of effective and situation-appropriate data visualisations for communicating the outcome of Machine Learning
- can apply knowledge to identify and solve problems using Machine Learning
- masters descriptive statistical techniques and tools to evaluate and prepare data for Machine Learning modelling
- masters relevant tools and techniques for programming applications that utilize Machine Learning
- masters relevant tools, materials and techniques to solve real-world IT problems
- can find information relevant to developing Machine Learning applications
- can study a data problem situation and identify code and optimisation issues and what measures need to be implemented to solve the problem
- understands the ethical guidelines and codes of conduct that apply in Machine Learning
- can carry out Machine Learning projects using problem that can be solved using applied Machine Learning
- can build relations with his/her peers across discipline boundaries and with external target groups
- can develop Machine Learning applications using programming languages
- can develop work methods and present the results of Machine Learning applications

My questions are, is this course worth taking? will the skills learnt be relevant to the job market in approx. fall 2023?

Thank you for your response :)

Comment: Do you want to work with IT or with ML? The list includes many purely ML items. The two are non-exclusive, but perhaps a course more tailored to IT could be better?

Answer (score 0):

I think the content of the course will still be relevant for several reasons.
The first one is that the courses available will always slightly lag the state of the art research as it takes a bit of time for a new tool to be widely used and known.
The second is that even if progresses are being made fast in some domains, this course seems to cover the general foundation on which you can build a deeper knowledge yourself by maybe going a bit more specialized. I refer here to the variety of problems machine learning now covers, from images to sounds to languages.
Third reason is that companies evolve A LOT slower than academia on tech related questions. Yes there will be some teams that are state of the art, but overall, companies care most about robustness and loss aversion than fancy and shiny new models, therefore you can be sure some companies will still be in need to whatever is taught in that course.
As pointed out @Firebug however, machine learning is just a very small sub-domain of IT, and this course material seems to be centered on it. It is yours now to decide if that's what you want to do.